# attributes method causing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working through agile web development with rails 4th edition (rails 3.2+). Long story short, I ended up messing somethings up so I copied the correct code from the books website into the proper files. Specifically, I was working on some functional test, which is the code I replaced. When I ran:

```
rake test:functionals
```

I got:

```
0 failures, 6 errors
```

Every error is this:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes:
```

Having dealt with this error before, I was able to deduce that the 6 erros are coming from the 6 attributes methods that were in the code I copied and pasted. Here are some examples from various functional tests:

```
test "should update cart" do
    put :update, id: @cart, cart: **@cart.attributes**
    assert_redirected_to cart_path(assigns(:cart))
  end

test "should update order" do
    put :update, id: @order, order: **@order.attributes**
    assert_redirected_to order_path(assigns(:order))
  end

test "should update line_item" do
    put :update, id: @line_item, line_item: **@line_item.attributes**
    assert_redirected_to line_item_path(assigns(:line_item))
  end
```

Now, I also know that the errors are due to attributes b/c they disappear if I replace them with a hash:

```
model: {attribute: value, attribute: value, attribute: value, etc. }
```

instead of:

```
model: @model.attributes
```

All the the attributes being assigned are in my attr_accessible method in my models. Thus, I truly cannot figure out why the attributes method is not working. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that when you replace `@model.attributes` with a hash, you put in the same attributes? Looks like some of the model attributes that are returned by `attributes` method are not white-listed by `attr_accessible`, but when you are replacing it with a hash you only use whitelisted ones.

Comment: Yea, you are completely right. The details of the errors back this up because when the mass assignment error appears, it references the 'updated_at', 'created_at', and 'id' attributes. Good call.

Comment: out of curiosity, do you know of any methods or helpers that only would only output whitelisted attributes?

Comment: Hmm, quick guess would be to use something like `@model.attributes.slice(*Model.accessible_attributes)`